# With react-router how to find out if on the last route?

Tags: react-router

In the examples the assumption seems to be that if you render a component for one route and then a second component for a child route you will want both components to fully render.

In our case we only want the last route's component to fully render. At the moment I'm doing some manual matching of the location pathname. But this is quite manual. I'm looking for a method to detect if the component we are in is the last one in the chain. Is there such a method? I thought it might be something to do with history.isActive() but this seems to mean that the route we are on is just part of the matched path - not the last one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a combination of component-less routes and `IndexRoute` in your route config. For example, if you specify your routes as

```
<Route path="foo">
  <IndexRoute component={NotParent} />
  <Route path="bar" component={NotChild} />
</Route>
```

In this case, `NotParent` will render on `foo`, while `NotChild` will render on `foo/bar`.